# VBA find and replace in a word doc's footer

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have a document that has a bunch of `<<system>>` in its footers.
So far I've just been highlighting them and pasting over, which is very tedious.
I would like VBA to do this for me.

I have a macro written that takes care of all the find and replaces in the document, except it isn't working in the footers.

Looking on google, it seems that all I'm finding is how to do it with the vba in word, but I need to work from vba in excel. Is it possible to make it work from there?

vba used (works for everything in the word doc except the stuff in the footers):

```
Dim objword
Set objword = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

With objword.ActiveDocument.Content
    With .Find
        .Execute FindText:="thing to search", ReplaceWith:="thing to replace", Replace:=1 '(or 2)
    End With
End With
```

Comment: *Second question* belongs in a separate post. This is a question and answer site - note that *question* is singular, not plural.

Comment: Ok, I removed the second question and will ask it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Life is a lot easier if you add a reference to Word objects in Excel, but otherwise, this might work from Excel:

```
Public Sub UpdateWord()

Dim wrdObj As Object    ' Application object
Dim wrdDoc As Object    ' Word object
Dim sect As Object      ' Section
Dim footr As Object     ' Footer
Dim sel As Object       ' Selection

Dim kwrd_find As String: kwrd_find = "<<system>>" ''' Keyword to find
Dim kwrd_replace As String: kwrd_replace = "Hello" ''' Word to replace keyword

Dim DocPath As String: DocPath = "C:\path\to\my\word-document.docx"

Set wrdObj = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

''' Open word document
''' Change `Visible` to False if you don't want to see it.
Set wrdDoc = wrdObj.Documents.Open(DocPath, ReadOnly:=False, Visible:=True)

On Error Resume Next

With wrdDoc
    ''' Run through all sections and footers (you can add headers, too).
    For Each sect In .Sections
        For Each footr In sect.Footers
            With footr.Range.Find
                .Text = kwrd_find                ''' Keyword to find
                .Replacement.Text = kwrd_replace ''' Word to replace keyword
                .Wrap = wdFindContinue ''' Wrap it up.
                Call .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceAll)
            End With
        Next
    Next sect
End With

''' Close and save document
Call wrdDoc.Close(SaveChanges:=True)

''' Clean up e'rything.
Set wrdDoc = Nothing
Set wrdObj = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: It works pretty well, thanks! Only thing is afterward it leaves the word doc's view as something strange and I have to click 'Print Layout' under View to set it back to normal. Do you know what the VBA code is to do that automatically? I'm having trouble finding that. Note that I'm omitting the code to close the word doc as I want to keep it open.

Comment: Sure thing.  On the .Close() method, there's a couple of other options.  One is OriginalFormat, which can take one of three options.  You could try `wrdDoc.Close(SaveChages:=True, OriginalFormat:=wdOriginalDocumentFormat)`.  Save() reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Word.Document.Close(method). Formatting enum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdoriginalformat

Comment: @workinonvba - The view is changed because the code is selecting the footer, which is completely unnecessary. Delete the two lines of code following `For Each footr In sect.Footers` and change `With sel.Find` to `With footr.Range.Find`.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks for the heads up!  I admittedly haven't worked with this kind of code before, so I really appreciate the suggestions.  Will OP still need to specify a save format?

Comment: “Will OP still need to specify a save format?” - no. `OriginalFormat` refers to the `SaveFormat`, i.e. docx, docm, dotx, dotm, etc., and has no effect on the view type.

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks again, @TimothyRylatt!